# Adding Images on 2D JButton Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a two dimensional JButton array and I want to add to each button a different image. These images are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg...

There are a total of 27 buttons (3x9 grid), so setting them manually would be tiresome. I tried it with an ImageIcon array and for-loops, but it doesn't work. Does somebody got an idea what's wrong with my code?

```
void createButtons() {
        JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][9];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setIcon(addImages());
            }
        }
    }

ImageIcon addImages() {

    ImageIcon[] images = new ImageIcon[27];
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new ImageIcon(i + ".jpg");
        return images[i];
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using for-loop in addImages()? It will terminate in first iteration because you return value there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your addImages method will always return a new Image Icon with 0.jpg.

You can do this instead:

```
void createButtons() {
        JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][9];
        int index = 1;  //start from 1.jpg
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon( (index++) + ".jpg"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TomCollins Try it and let me know the outcome.

Comment: @TomCollins If it doesn't work, then some other parts of your codes might be causing it. we will have to see the entire codes..

Comment: @TomCollins Great, if it solves your problem, you can accept the solution here by clicking the `hollow tick` beside one of our solution which helps you best. You get 2 rep points in return. (You can only accept one solution for each question)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a method that should be used **once** to make all the images with another method to fetch the **one** image you need.  Try this:

```
ImageIcon[] addImages() {
    ImageIcon[] images = new ImageIcon[27];
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new ImageIcon(i + ".jpg");
    }
    return images;
}
```

Then you can call `addImages()` and reference the array:

```
void createButtons() {
        ImageIcon[] images = addImages();  // called once here
        JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][9];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setIcon(images[i * buttons[i].length + j]);  // then use it here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. Others said I should do everything in one method, so I will combine them. But I learned what my mistake exactly was, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image directly in the loop:

```
void createButtons() {
    JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
            buttons[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon((i * 9 + j) + ".jpg"));
        }
    }
}
```

There is not need for a whole method for this (what's more, it's written incorrectly).

**Edit:** the problem with `addImages()`

Your `addImages()` method is iterated over, each time it creates a new `ImageIcon[]` which, if at all, should be created only once (outside of any loop). Inside, you start iterating over the array, but stop at the first iteration, `i=0`, because your `return images[0]`. This method will always return the same value.

Comment: Thanks, the first button is empty but the rest appear (I think it's because i = 0 in the first iteration?).
Can you explain what is wrong with my method (beside being superfluous)? I'm still new to Java.

Comment: @TomCollins "*the first button is empty*" It has to do with the names of the files which I can't know. If you numbered them correctly then just adjust the index to match. I edited my question to explain what's wrong with your method.